# Reading a sequence until the empty line

Tags: java, object, methods

I am writing a Java program. I need help with the input of the program, that is a sequence of lines containing two tokens separated by one or more spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArrayCustomer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer[] array = new Customer[5];
    Scanner aScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int index = readInput(aScanner, array);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use `value.trim().length()`

The `trim()` method will remove extra spaces if any.

Also `String` is assigned to `Customer` you will need to create a object out of the `String` of type `Customer` before assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... You can put the file you want to read from where "stuff.txt" currently is.  This code uses the split() method from the String class to tokenize each line of text until the end of the file.  In the code the split() method splits each line based on a space.  This method takes a regex such as the empty space in this code to determine how to tokenize.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile { 

static ArrayList<String> AL = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    try { 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stuff.txt"));
        String datLine; 
        while((datLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                AL.add(datLine);  // add line of text to ArrayList

                System.out.println(datLine);  //print line
        }
        System.out.println("tokenizing...");




        //loop through String array
        for(String x: AL) { 
                //split each line into 2 segments based on the space between them
                String[] tokens = x.split(" ");
            //loop through the tokens array
            for(int j=0; j<tokens.length; j++) { 
                    //only print if j is a multiple of two and j+1 is not greater or equal to the length of the tokens array to preven ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
                    if ( j % 2 ==0 && (j+1) < tokens.length) { 
                            System.out.println(tokens[j] + " " +  tokens[j+1]);
                    }
            }

        }


} catch(IOException ioe) { 
        System.out.println("this was thrown: " + ioe);

}

}



}
```